# Markov Chain Coin Flips

Tags: probability

If you flip a fair coin $n$ times, what is the probability that the $n$th flip is the first time in your series of flips that completes a pair of consecutive heads?

Comment: Since you mentioned Markov chains, consider the states "not after head and have not seen a pair yet", "after head and have not seen a pair yet", "have just completed the first pair of heads", "have seen a pair of heads in the past" ans the corresponding transition probabilities. We start in the first state and wonder what the probability to be in the third state is.

Answer (score 3):

Let $a_k$ be the number of sequences of H and/or T of length $k$ that end in H and have no two consecutive H. Let $b_k$ be the number of sequences of length $k$ that end in T and have no two consecutive H.

Note that the number of sequences of length $n$ such that the first two consecutive H occur at the end is $a_{n-1}$. So our probability is $\frac{a_{n-1}}{2^n}$.

Now we go after $a_n$ and $b_n$. We have the recurrences
$$a_n=b_{n-1},$$
and
$$b_n=a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}.$$
We assume that you can handle finding $a_n$ and $b_n$. Please indicate if there is some difficulty.